# detecting when an iOS UICollectionCell is going off screen

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

I'm having a `UICollectionView` that holds pictures as elements in its datastore.

I want to load a high resolution pic into the element only when its corresponding `UICollectionViewCell` is currently showing on screen. Later, when the `UICollectionViewCell` goes off screen, I want to return the element's `UIImage` into the low resolution version.

My question is, how can I detect when a `UICollectionViewCell` is going off screen?

(I tried using the `prepareForReuse` method but I can't predict when it will be called).

I'm currently using a piece of code that sits in `scrollViewDidScroll`, and every time that the view scrolls I'm checking the `self.collectionView.visibleCells` to see which cells has scrolled off screen.

It seems a bit of an overhead and I wonder if there is a method called on the `UICollectionViewCell` itself whenever it is being scrolled of screen ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:) method on `UICollectionViewDelegate` should do what you want.

Comment: Only issue with this method is that it also gets called when the 'collectionView` receives a `reloadData` message

Comment: @Mazyod yes, sometimes  some cell on screen is passed to `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: You can put `guard !collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(indexPath) else { return }`. It's not such elegant but it will work.

Answer (score 5):

From Documentation. collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell is called right after it finishes displaying, not when it goes off screen

Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a collection view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it disappears

Answer (score -1):

`collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` is the correct method to detect when a cell has gone from screen.

Meanwhile, I think it's more correct **not** to perform cleanup in `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` but to tell your cell to perform cleanup itself:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                 didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                   forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.prepareForReuse()
  }
```

With this approach your `UICollectionViewDelegate` doesn't have to know any implementation details of your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. In the cell we'll override `prepareForReuse` method:

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    imageView.image = lowResolutionImage
    highResolutionImage = nil
 }
```

Comment: prepareForReuse() is called by the framework before a cell is dequeued with dequeueReusableCell(...). I recon that in you case you could clean up before reuse but that keeps the memory allocated until the cell has to be reused. If you want to accommodate memory issues the correct solution will be to deallocate your memory when the cell ends displaying.