# How to determine indexPath of currently visible UICollectionView cell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to display some cell-specific text, but I can’t extricate the visible cell from the collection view.

Most helpful ones were these:

[how to access from UICollectionViewCell the indexPath of the Cell in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875428/how-to-access-from-uicollectionviewcell-the-indexpath-of-the-cell-in-uicollectio)

[detecting when an iOS UICollectionCell is going off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465489/detecting-when-an-ios-uicollectioncell-is-going-off-screen)

A lower collection view (self addSubview) contains possible items.  An upper one (self addSubview) contains selections from the lower.  The user presses a button (self addSubview again), the lower view scrolls off to oblivion and the upper one expands such that one cell fills the screen.  All the array-building and displaying works fine.  No *.nibs.

What doesn’t work is figuring out which cell the app is presenting to the user.

TRY #1: First I tried populating the UILabel in parallel with normal ops. Press the button and cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
if (cv.tag == UPPER_CV_TAG) {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath;
tempIndexPath = itemAttributes.indexPath;
NSLog(@"cellForItem indexPath %@",indexPath);
NSLog(@"layout indexPath %@",tempIndexPath);
}
```

responds as you’d expect:

```
cellForItem indexPath <blah blah> 2 indexes [0, 0]
layout indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 0]

cellForItem indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 1]
layout indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 1]

cellForItem indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 2]
layout indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 2]
```

When the gyrations conclude, Cell 0 correctly occupies center stage.  Unfortunately, so does the description for cell 2.  Scroll left / right, cells change accordingly, the corresponding text does not.  It remains constant: that which maps to cell 2.

Obviously I’m passing the wrong index to the description array.

TRY #2: OK, fine.  I’ll interrogate a point I know the currently visible cell occupies and reason backward from that.

```
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(512, 456);
NSIndexPath *theCellsIndexPath = [self.upper_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
NSLog(@"theCellsIndexPath=%d",theCellsIndexPath.item);
```

No cigar:

```
cellForItem indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 0]
theCellsIndexPath=0

cellForItem indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 1]
theCellsIndexPath=0

cellForItem indexPath < > 2 indexes [0, 2]
theCellsIndexPath=0
```

No change from “0” when I change 512,456 to other likely points. No change from “0” when I use layoutAttributes to determine where in the view the cell lies, just in case.  Nope, that cell is a really, really big target.  I’m not missing it.

TRY #3: Maybe I’m working too hard.  I’ll trap the goings-on inside

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
}
```

and roll with that.

Nope.  It never gets called.

TRY #4: Since I don’t know the indexPath of the single cell on the screen (but the collectionView does) I suppose I could iterate through all the cells with didEndDisplayingCell until I hit “Bingo!”  That’s crude and indicative of programmer error.

I’m glad the collectionView logic buffers three cells.  Probably improves user experience or something.  But where it ends up – on 0 – is not where my array index last knew it was – at 2.

What part of the docs didn’t I read?

Comment: `indexPathForCell:` doesn't work?

Comment: Does `[UICollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]` not work for you?

Answer (score 12):

> *What part of the docs didn’t I read?*

[`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) has a method called [`indexPathsForVisibleItems`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForVisibleItems) . Make sure you read it through to see what else you can use from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try `collectionView.visibleCells`

```
NSArray *ary = collectionView.visibleCells;
for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in ary) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"indexPath of cell: Section: %d , Row: %d", (int)path.section, (int)path.row);
}
```